Clicking at certain places minimizes the window in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
When i click on new tab, the browser minimizes and i am thrown back to previous window  I have attached the behaviour link here
I am a new user, Sorry if it's a silly question

Certain places, do you mean the top bar?

@amar No not top bar, it happens when i click somewhere in the application, sometimes on the browser tab, sometimes a video playing in VLC

If there is no other problems see if this helps https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/
